# Java SSL/TLS Connection with ECC based certificates

Tags: java, ssl, ecdsa

I'm trying to build a Server which works with ECC-based certificates. So far I have taken the following steps:

1) creating the signed server-certificate with openssl:

```
openssl ecparam -param_enc explicit -out server\server.key.pem -name secp256k1 -genkey
openssl req -new -nodes -key server\server.key.pem -outform pem -out server\server.csr -sha256
openssl ca -keyfile CA\private\ca.key.pem -cert CA\ca.cert.pem -in server\server.csr -out server\server-cert.pem -md sha256 -outdir .\server
openssl pkcs12 -export -out server\server-cert.p12 -inkey server\server.key.pem -in server\server-cert.pem -certfile CA\ca.cert.pem
```

The ca.sert.pem is a self-signed CA-certificate to sign the server certificate with. It is generated likewise:

```
openssl ecparam -param_enc explicit -out CA\private\ca.key.pem -name secp256k1 -genkey 
openssl req -new -key CA\private\ca.key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 365 -outform pem -sha256 -out CA\ca.cert.pem
```

2) setting up the server

```
    public void startServer() {
    threadPool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    threadPool.setCorePoolSize(20);

    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();
  SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
  SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888);
        String[] ciphers = {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"};
  serverSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphers);
  serverSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});

  while (true) {
    SSLSocket clientSocket = (SSLSocket) serverSocket.accept();
    threadPool.execute(new ClientSession(clientSocket));
  }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    protected SSLContext getSSLContextForGWA() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
        File keyFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "certs" + File.separator + "server" + File.separator + "server-cert.p12");
        FileInputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(keyFile);
        ks.load(keyInput, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        keyInput.close();

        // Set up key manager factory to use our key store
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        // Initialize the SSLContext to work with our key managers.
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

        return sslContext;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Remark: I only succeed to load the server certificate into the keystore using BouncyCastle. Otherwise I get "Only named ECParameters supported" Error.

3) Setting up the client
The client is set up likewise, except that the server certificate is imported into the truststore.

```
    SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContextForSMGW();
    SSLSocketFactory sf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

    SSLSocket clientSocket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket(host, port);
    String[] ciphers = {"TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"};
    clientSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(ciphers);
    clientSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
    printClientSocketInfo(clientSocket);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

String line = null;
while (((line = in.readLine()) != null)) {
  System.out.println(line);
  break;
}
```

Now, when the client connects to the server I get the following error stack:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
at sun.security.ec.ECParameters.engineInit(ECParameters.java:150)
at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293)
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.decodeParams(AlgorithmId.java:132)
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.<init>(AlgorithmId.java:114)
at sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId.parse(AlgorithmId.java:372)
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.parse(X509Key.java:168)
at sun.security.x509.CertificateX509Key.<init>(CertificateX509Key.java:75)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:667)
at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
... 15 more
```

I guess, that the client is not capable to verify the servers certificate (same error as if I import the certificate not using BouncyCastle).

I have printed the named EC-Curves with

```
        System.out.println("Named EC-Curves:");
    String[] curves = Security.getProvider("SunEC")
            .getProperty("AlgorithmParameters.EC SupportedCurves")
            .split("\\|");
    for (String curve : curves) {
        System.out.println(curve.substring(1, curve.indexOf(",")));
    }
```

And it clearly outputs the name 'secp256k1' among them. So what am I missing here? Or how can I make the SSLContext to use another implementation of CertificateX509Key?

The debug output at the client side is:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1427463640 bytes = { 227, 188, 124, 163, 124, 55, 134, 199, 234, 241, 234, 51, 8, 208, 199, 117, 90, 125, 214, 134, 226, 110, 149, 92, 194, 25, 70, 59 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 144
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 1540
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1427463640 bytes = { 155, 184, 16, 18, 186, 249, 50, 70, 182, 75, 129, 217, 165, 78, 228, 255, 138, 98, 193, 58, 229, 70, 45, 1, 244, 84, 187, 235 }
Session ID:  {85, 21, 94, 216, 168, 186, 180, 208, 21, 40, 84, 147, 20, 244, 43, 97, 214, 18, 173, 27, 52, 175, 44, 1, 127, 20, 62, 126, 65, 229, 79, 1}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
** TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket()
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: java.io.IOException: Only named ECParameters supported
   Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
   Protocol = NONE
```

The curve is listed also among the curve-names. I have tried so many things now, I'm kind of stuck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: **Don't use -param_enc explicit.** That *discards* the "named" (actually OID) form of curve encoding and uses the "arbitrary" curve encoding instead. When SunEC says "only named curves supported" it probably means only curves in named *form*, not curves with prime/poly and coefficients etc etc that happen to match the values for a curve that has a name. I'm a bit surprised Bouncy *does* support arbitrary, since I don't there's anyone else that will interoperate with it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Generating the certificates without the _-param_enc explicit_ option did the trick. The certificates can now be imported into the standard KeyStore and the communication works.